# Creating Variables By string text

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking to create variables by string value. Is there smarter way to do it?

```
if (str == "DateTime")
{
        DateTime d = new DateTime();
}

else if( str == "TimeSpan")
{
        TimeSpan s = new TimeSpan();
}
```

I want to write something like that:

```
object o = new someString() ` when someString is "DateTime" or "TimeSpan"`
```

Comment: what is the purpose behind that? looks like a xy-problem

Comment: you should be aware that even *if* that were possible - which it is technically - `O`s type will allways be just `object`. So you can't do much with it. You'd have to cast it to the underlying **runtime**-type, which you don't know at **compile**-time.

Comment: What value does a default `DateTime` value actually have? Not as in "what is the value of the object" but more like "what do you intend to do with it, how is this useful for your program"? Same with `TimeSpan`, in both cases they will sort of have a "zero" value, or some default low value. I just don't see what you intend to do with these.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this which does the same thing but more concisely:

```
object o = str switch
{
    "DateTime" => new DateTime(),
    "TimeSpan" => new TimeSpan(),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
};
```

It would be helpful to know what you want to do with the variable afterwards, however, because there might be better ways if you provide context.

Comment: hi 
I have oracle Table that one column represents type in c#
And I want to dynamically  assign variables by the text in my column.
Without the need of refactoring my c# code 

hope I'm understandable
thanks

Comment: How are you using the variables afterwards? Do you store them as a DateTime/TimeSpan within an object? Do you store them in a List<object> where you have a mix of DateTimes and TimeSpans? So in essence, do you need the variables to be proper DateTimes or TimeSpans or will you need them as objects?

Comment: Objects its fine and do the works

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the dynamic variables, and check the type of it in runtime.
eg:

```
dynamic str ;
        str = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if(str.GetType()==typeof(System.TimeSpan))
        {
            Console.Write("hello");
        }
```